# Executing Jar File in JDK 1.6 giving issues

Tags: java

I have created a simple project in java using eclipse ide to test the log4j functionality.
I need to run the application from the command prompt using the jar tool in java.
The logtest.java file is simple java file which defines a logger as below.
It is referencing a Logger which is in another Jar file. below is directory structure.

```
package com;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class logtest {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(logtest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("---------------HIIIIII-----------");
    }
```

Below is the directory structure that i have created in the project in eclipse.

```
src/com/logtest.java

lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

the manifest files entries are as below and i have manually created the maifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.logtest
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

The contents of the Jar file are as below which i unzipped using the jar utility.

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
.project
com/logtest.class
manifest.mf
lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
.classpath
```

I have exported the jar file and when i try to run using the commond java -jar JarTest2.jar i am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.logtest.<clinit>(logtest.java:6)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I know its a class not found exception but strange thing is that the same jar when i create using jdk1.5 and run command tool the jar runs successfully and the java class executes without any error.

I have no idea why this is going as everything is the same.

mine is a 64 bit windows 7 machine and the other machine where it is running is a 32 bit XP machine.

Of course the version of eclipse ide is different on both machines.

Can you please let me know is there something wrong about what i am doing or am i missing something else.

Thanks
Vikeng21

Comment: You said you want to test Log4j?
But in your `main` method you are using `System.out.println`, well that's not `log4j`.

Comment: Hi Amir. well my intention here is to see that the logger is to work correctly and gets recognized from another jar file(log4j.jar) which is in another directory. the sys out is just for testing purposes and i don't think it dosen't matter here whether its there or not but please stress on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Java doesn't support embedded Jars. I'd recommend moving the lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar file out to the file system (so that it creates a sub folder ./lib within the same drctory as your executable Jar & see if that makes a difference.

If you really want to use embedded Jars, you could take a read of [One-Jar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-onejar/)

You should have a directory structure of

```
.\JarTest2.jar
.\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

On your file system.  The `log4j` Jar shouldn't be imbedded (contained within) the `JarTest2.jar` file

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. can you please elaborate in more detail about what do you mean by a file system. An example would be very helpful for me to understand a little better. well what do you say about the strange thing thats going on in the 32 bit windows XP machine. how is java able to recognize the log4j jar there. just a bit curious about this disturbing behaviour.

Comment: See updates. I suspect that you dev machine has a class path setup that points the log4j.jar file some where on your file system

Comment: WOW thats works.Thanks a lot MadProgrammer. well i will have to change all the classpath settings for the other dependent jars based on this idea. i would also like to try OnJar but for now this is sufficient. thanks a lot to all.

Comment: been finding the problem for fews hours and finally is because of the naming of the `lib` folder, in eclipse it was `libs`. Recently i shifted the project to netbean. No wonder it wont run.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your log4j.jar is duplicated. For example one log4j.jar was under lib folder and other was under Referenced libraries of eclipse. If it is duplicated, remove one jar and redeploy again.

Comment: Thanks Sai.yes there is one under the reference libraries. i tried to delete the log4j jar under the reference libraries but the delet option is not enabled. can you let me know how i can delete and later i can redeploy. I am using Eclipse Indigo for dev.

Comment: @vikeng21 right-click on reference libraries and Build Path > Configure Build Path then select log4j.jar and remove it.You should add log4j.jar under lib folder only.

Comment: sai i have done as you said but after removing the log4j.jar from the reference libraries it gets removed from the classpath and the java class starts showing errors. did you see my folder structure. i am pointing all classes in the src folder to point to the lib directory where the log4j.jar is present. Is this correct or something is missing here. I want a single jar with all the dependent jars inside it

Comment: @vikeng21 create new folder that named 'lib' on your classpath means it is the same level at src folder and add log4j.jar into it.

Comment: Thanks Sai for your help also. what i did was that i alltogeather moved the log4j.jar outside of my project and pointed classpath to point to this path. i have the following directory structure now .\JarTest2.jar  and .\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar. Now the code is recognizing the logger. thanks a lot once again